# No reaction for the button

Tags: java, ajax, jsf, primefaces

I have a table:

```
<h:form id="form">
                <p:dataTable id="table" styleClass="table" value="#{userMB.allAdmins}" var="admin" paginator="true" rows="15" rowKey="#{admin.id}" selection="#{userMB.user}" selectionMode="single"  >
```

and in table i have a ajax:

```
<p:ajax event="rowSelect" listener="#{tableBean.onRowSelect()}" update=":form:table" />
```

my tableBean:

```
@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class TableBean {

    boolean flag = true;

    /**
     * Creates a new instance of TableBean
     */
    public TableBean() {
    }

    public boolean getFlag() {
        return flag;
    }

    public void setFlag(boolean flag) {
        this.flag = flag;
    }

    public void onRowSelect() {
        flag = false;
    }
}
```

When i select row i my edit button is enabled, otherwise disabled. My button:

```
<p:commandButton action="#{userMB.editStart()}" value="#{msg.edit}" disabled="#{tableBean.flag}" ajax="false" icon="ui-icon-pencil"/>
```

Method editStart:

```
   public String editStart() {
        return "editStart";
    }
```

only for navigation:

```
 <navigation-case>
            <from-outcome>editStart</from-outcome>
            <to-view-id>/protected/admin/adminEdit.xhtml</to-view-id>
        </navigation-case>
```

My problem is when i clic edit button i not go to the page adminEdit only my acutal page adminList refresh... Why?

Comment: Have you tried like this `<p:commandButton action="editStart" value="#{msg.edit}" disabled="#{tableBean.flag}" ajax="false" icon="ui-icon-pencil"/>'?

Comment: Is it working if you do `action="editStart"` directly? If not, probably, JSF is not parsing your config file.

Comment: I fix it. I chanhe my tableBean from requestScoped to viewScoped

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2118656/hcommandlink-hcommandbutton-is-not-being-invoked)?

It lists the common causes of this effect. I think number 4 could be your problem.